# Bash script function return value problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, return-value

Can anyone help me return the correct value from a bash script function?

Here's my function that should return first (and only) line of the file passed as an argument:

```
LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME()
{
    return_value=`awk 'NR==1' $1`
    return return_value
}
```

And here's my call of that function in the other script:

```
LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME "logfile"
timestamp=$?
echo "Timestamp = $timestamp"
```

I always get some random values with this code. If, for example, there's a value of 62772031 in the "logfile", I get

> Timestamp = 255

as an output. For some other values in the file, I get other random values as a return value, never the correct one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exit code is limited to `0 - 255`, you cannot use it for a timestamp.

Echo your timestamp instead, since you don't seem to be outputing anything else; this ought to be fine?

```
LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME()
{
    # If you want to do some more stuff, you might want
    # to use the intermediate variable as you first did.
    awk 'NR==1' $1
}

timestamp=$(LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME "logfile")
echo "Timestamp = $timestamp"
```

You might have simplified the function in your example, because if all you wanted was the first line, why not use `head -1 logfile` instead?

Comment: Do you know how could I do this in sh, instead of bash. In sh 
timestamp=$(LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME "logfile")
doesn't work. It says
'timestamp=$' unexpected

Comment: @Eedoh try using backticks, `timestamp=\`...\``

Answer (score 7):

Shell functions work like commands. They can only return errorlevel values (integers). To get strings you can either set a global variable, or print/echo the value and then have the caller use the command substitution (like back-ticks).

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME()
{
    return_value=`awk 'NR==1' $1`
    echo $return_value
}

timestamp=$(LOG_FILE_CREATION_TIME $1)

echo $timestamp
```

Unrelated, but BTW in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import sys
print open(sys.argv[1]).readline()
```

;-)

Comment: Really, Python to perform `head -1`? There will be *A LOT* of answers if we were to implement it in all languages...

Comment: @plundra I'm assuming there will be more to this program than this. Sure, head -1 works best for a one-time thing. I was hinting that the OP might go down a different path than writing a large program with functions in shell.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a global variable. You can have multiple "return" variables this way.
It does not actually return anything, but does the trick.

```
#!/bin/sh
concat_ret
concat() {
 for s in $*
 do
 concat_ret="$concat_ret $s"
 done
 return 0
}
echo "starting"
concat String1 String2 String3 "and many other strings"
echo $?
echo $concat_ret
exit 0
```

Output

```
starting
0
String1 String2 String3 and many other strings
```